# Simple Makefile for automating parallel grep is returning an error

Tags: makefile, gnu-parallel

I often use Makefiles for automating tasks I do repeatedly. For example, one task involves searching a growing dataset for regular expression matches. Suppose I have the following two text files, `search1.txt`, and `search2.txt`:

`search1.txt`:

```
DSADJKBSDJSA
TEST1
DJKSABVDJSA
```

`search2.txt`:

```
hvdsjhavdjshavdsa
dsadsadsadsa
TEST3djsabdjhsavdjhsa
TEST2dsajdbsahjdvsa
```

Here's my Makefile to search these in parallel using GNU parallel.

```
.PHONY: search
search:
    find search*.txt | parallel grep TEST1 {}
    find search*.txt | parallel grep TEST2 {}
```

When I run `make search`, the first line outputs the correct data and then throws an error and quits, despite the fact that running both lines on their own complete just fine.

```
> make search
find *.txt | parallel grep TEST1 {}
TEST1
make: *** [search] Error 1
> find *.txt | parallel grep TEST1 {}
TEST1
> find *.txt | parallel grep TEST2 {}
TEST2dsajdbsahjdvsa
> parallel --version
GNU parallel 20160822
```

I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong. It must be something obvious, but I've distilled this down to such a small simple example, and I'm still confused as to why this is happening. Thanks for any help I get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah ha! I figured it out. Turns out that grep has an exit status that is causing this. From the grep man pages:

```
EXIT STATUS
     The grep utility exits with one of the following values:

     0     One or more lines were selected.
     1     No lines were selected.
     >1    An error occurred.
```

Since some of the files I'm searching will not contain the match, grep will return an exit status of 1. This has a pretty simple fix:

```
.PHONY: search
search:
    find search*.txt | parallel grep TEST1 {} || true
    find search*.txt | parallel grep TEST2 {} || true
```